# Intercept bluetooh reads in C# of a HID device?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I need to read directly the reads of a barcode reader. It is adhered to USB HID specification and uses bluetooh as a transport layer.

I detected the bluetooth devices using:

```
    var selector = Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
```

but I do not know how to claim the control. For RfcommDevices, I did:

```
    var dev = RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(DeviceId);
    var rfcommService = await dev;
```

and then I could open a socket. Now, it is different, it is based on HDI and I am not clear how can I claim the control.

What I need to do is to read anything that the barcode reads and to manage it. I do not want that Windows manages directly the barcode reader as if it was a keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to directly claim control of the HID device over Bluetooth. This is to aid user privacy. You should use the [Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice.aspx) set of APIs to connect to your HID device and interact with it.

Comment: After research, I see you were right. Fortunally the scanner can be set to SPP mode and then it is a lot easier since it does not use the HID mode. Thank you